# How To Bootstrap Integrate with Codeigniter Form Validation

Tags: codeigniter, validation, twitter-bootstrap

How to just add highlight has-error and or has-success to codeigniter inputs for validation check.

I know there are java scripts out there for bootstrap 3 validation. But I have tried most of them.

I have my codeigniter validations working fine but would like to be able to add class **has-error to input** if codeigniter validation error is on.

And remove class **has-error** if OK and add class **has-success**

I know it can be done with java script, but the ones I have come across add extra required message which I don't need.

I am just after inputs changing color because I all ready have codeigniter validation message.

Same sort of effect but just with php codeigniter.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_db_hostname; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="db_hostname" value="<?php echo $db_hostname; ?>" class="form-control" size="50"/>
        <?php echo form_error('db_hostname', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want only add or remove `has-error` and `has-success` classes with some javascript code without showing some additional message?

Comment: I want to be able to have both working but for error messages use codeigniter one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the controller or model where you have the form validation code add

```
   $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');
```

then to display an error message for a specific form field - for example a field called 'username' - put this in your form code near the form input.

```
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
```

OR if you want to display all the errors together like at the top of the form

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

all the details at: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: I all ready know that as said I have codeigniter form validation working, trying to also get bootstrap form validation working with it. Just trying to get has-error, working and has-success for highlighting of input border. But using codeigniter messages. All the other bootstrap validations come with there own messages.

Comment: ok i see -- bootstrap 3 has different colors for the input frames. so either you are checking the form with jquery to validate and/or you are showing the form again and using CI form_error() to check if the field had an error or not. If you do use jquery to validate - doing a call for every field can cause the form to hang trying to get to the next field which is a real pain for the user. in terms of jquery validation i did find this which looks worth trying http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-form.html

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for...

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('username')){echo 'has-error';} ?>">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="">
</div>
```

That should work...

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter provides function called form_validation to do the validation of input data.

To show the error data you can use form_error() or validation_error() function of codeigniter.

In your CodeIgniter controller file below the form_validtion code enter the below code

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('field to check', 'your custum message for this field');
```

and then below your input filed in the view write the below code to display the error

```
<?php echo form_error('field for  which you want to show error'); ?>
```

**OR**

if you want to display all the error message together then you can use below code

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

For your reference, I add the below link to see how form_validation class of CodeIgniter work

[how to show error for input field using form validation class of codeigniter](http://codesquery.com/create-registration-form-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to validate your forms. If that is the case, I have found a nice and easy validator specifically for Bootstrap 3, it is called [BootstrapValidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com).

It is still a relatively young [repo](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator)(I think), in other words, it is going to be an active repo. and there is Support for it. I found it easy to use, and implement.

Comment: still shows bootstraps error message only need the input validation classes from bootstrap. I use the codeigniter error messages.

Answer (score 0):

you should also upgrade your version of codeigniter to 3.1.10, takes care of the errors